# Parsing a C# style hex string

Tags: vb.net, hex, binarywriter

I've got a problem with my code. I put the offset value into listbox, then I read it and seek it in file. I use the following code.

```
    Dim bw As New BinaryWriter(File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    Try
        For j As Integer = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
            czytana = ListBox2.Items.Item(j)
            tablica = czytana.Split(" ") ' czytana is in format OFFSET: BYTE BYTE, offset is a hex addr
            tablica(0) = tablica(0).Replace(":", "") 'I remove : from "OFFSET:"
            bw.BaseStream.Seek("&H" + tablica(0), SeekOrigin.Begin) ' in ex. I got tablica(0)=000CFDD6, and I want to get &HCFDD6, but what I get is &H000CFDD6
            'some part of code in here which does its job properly
        Next j
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    bw.Close()
```

the problem is: I need to use tablica(0) as an offset, tablica(1) and tablica(2) as bytes. What I want to do is open the file, select the offset and replace with tablica(2). czytana got a format "tablica(0): tablica(1) tablica(2).

Does somebody mind helping? :)

Comment: Provide stack trace or describe the problem. Unfortunately this site did not implement the widely available mind reading mechanism :-)

Comment: my problem is simple: I want to convert string to &H format. In example: I got tablica(0)=000CFDD6, and I want to get &HCFDD6, but what I get is &H000CFDD6, which causes troubles when I try to overwrite some bytes in later.

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson could you please read the question? His problem is that it gets the inputs in certain format and wants to convert it to the right format

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings, perhaps you should change the title of this question to something like "Converting to VB.NET hex format".

Comment: `&HCFDD6` and `&H000CFDD6` should produce exactly the same value. They both should produce a 32 bit integer with the upper 3 nybbles all 0.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever actually this seems to be the case. I have just posted my answer to fullfil the exact requirements of the OP (apparently he was complaining about not getting the right results). By seeing things in this way, my code does not seem to have a real point as far as it would be enough with replacing "0x" with &H. I guess that I have to delete my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Now, please describe your exact conditions. For example, include a list of input values in ListBox2 (such that we can understand the exact format and thus advise you about the best way through).

Comment: Its good that you've provided the code but you don't explain the specific problem, not in comments but in the question.

Comment: What I believe you want is to convert Hex String into number format.. then the number format back into HexString for saving to file.. for that use this, here is example `Dim test As Integer = &HAABBCCDD` now what you save to file is `test.ToString("X")` which will store `AABBCCDD` to file

Comment: Please take a look at my new answer and let me know if everything is clear now. I am showing the proper way to deal with your inputs (or this is what I understand from your comments); if you get any kind of error, it would mean that your inputs/the file they refer to are wrong.

Comment: BTW you have already various votes to close this question. If you don't want it to be closed, you should reword it properly (include some inputs) to explain your point exactly, that is: I have a list of Offsets/bytes and want to account for them via BinaryWriter. You are not even including all your code, neither answering the questions asked by people who wants to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, I understand that you have the following inputs:

```
OFFSET -> tablica(0). Sample Value: 000CFDD6
BYTE to write from OFFSET -> tablica(2). Sample Value: 6F
```

Your code should look like:

```
bw.BaseStream.Seek(curOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin)
bw.Write(curByte)
```

Where:

```
Dim curOffset As Long = Long.Parse(tablica(0), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
'An equivalent approach would be: Dim offset As Long = Int64.Parse("&H" & tablica(0))
'Where all the zeroes after &H (and before the first non-zero character) do not matter; &H0001 is the same than &H1
Dim curByte as Byte = Byte.Parse(Integer.Parse(tablica(2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber))
```

Comment: Thank You, varocarbas. Your code works and is the answer for my problems and questions. I also found a solution. I just did 
                zastępujący = Convert.ToByte(tablica(2).ToString, 16)

Comment: @JanBońkowski OK. But as said, if you want this question to be helpful to others (and to not be deleted), you should write it a bit differently: letting clear the inputs you are expecting (hex values as strings) and what you want to do. Your problems is not knowing how to deal with binaryWriter and with offset/bytes and hex format. Please, explain this point better.

Comment: -1 why? Downvoter, could you please explain me what is wrong with my answer? ah! I know who are you: pfff... Anyway. BTW (, coward, ), the difference between your (deleted) question and this answer is that this answer gives a solution for what the OP wants. If what the OP wants is not good for this site, his question should be deleted, but there is nothing wrong with this answer (which, additionaly, is written in a pretty generic way).